# Download file from linux server once it is created

Tags: linux, download

I recently started to work with Linux server, I am very new. My CUDA/C++ program solves 2D differential equation and writes down output every, say, 1000 time steps. It happens roughly every minute.

**Is it possible to automatically download files to my PC once they are generated on the Linux server, or save them directly to my PC?**

This would significantly accelerate my work since now I have to wait for my program to finish all the calculations and then download it manually. I also typically use 6 GPUS at the same time, they produce output in different specified folders on the LINUX server (say, folders `0`, `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`).

Comment: "Is it possible to automatically download files to my PC once they generated on the Linux server" - Yes;  You can write code that will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use *inotify-wait* a command which is part of the *inotify-tools* package. Create a file, called for instance *my_monitor*, with content

```
#!/bin/bash
while true # will loop forever!
do 
   inotify-wait -r -e modify,attrib,close_write,move,create,delete /path/to/dir/or/file/to/monitor && /path/to/script
done
```

*inotify-wait* monitors a directory or a file (and, if you add the flag *-r*, it will monitor the whole directory tree recursively) for changes. I have selected some typical changes to watch for, and you can find an exhaustive list [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait); *inotify-wait* terminates as soon as **one** event in the list above occurs, and the command above then executes some *bash* script (which you have to write) that will copy the files you need to your other machine. As soon as the file transfer completes, the cycle starts again.

You can start the script above with

```
nohup /path/to/my_monitor
```

which means that, even if you log out from this pc, the script will *not* stop working: basically, it will run forever (*i.e.*, until reboot).

That's all.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Say, on Linux server my file is created in the directory: `share-home/genkin/0`, and I want to download it to my PC to the folder `C:\data\0`

Answer (score 1):

You can run a simple server on the Linux machine that serves the generated files, e.g. `cd` to the desired directory and run:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then on the home PC you can use `wget` to periodically download the new stuff (as achieved with `-N`):

```
while true; do
    wget -rN http://server/
    sleep 60
done
```

If you are running Windows at home, you can get Wget for Windows and write the above as a `BAT` script, or use a different downloader that does that kind of mirroring natively.