# List or update contents of a directory when modified (ie new file created or file deleted) to a text file

Tags: linux, bash, crontab, inotify

I use linux mint and I want a text file to reflect the changes of files in a directory, it should contain the names of files that exist in the directory and add newly created files automatically. I referred some links and it said a good way to do it is by using the `inotify-tools`. I did look up on that and came up with this bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -qqe modify path-of-directory ; do 
ls > path-of-text-file;
done
```

But it doesn't seem to work, Kindly guide me on how to go about it and is it enough if I just add this script to the list of start-up applications to keep it running all the time or should I use a `crontab`?

Comment: With a simple `>` redirection, the file will be overwritten on any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) states that `modify` triggers when a file is written to. You probably want to monitor `create`, `delete` and `move` events.

Check [this more elaborate answer to similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1152448/432690). There's `nohup` command mentioned there. Another useful command might be `disown`.

---

I think looping `inotifywait` may miss an event when it occurs during the execution of `ls` (because there's no `inotifywait` running at this exact  moment). There are `-m` and `-d` options, they should miss nothing. This approach should be a little more reliable:

```
inotifywait -me create,delete,move path-of-directory | while read a ; do ls > path-of-text-file; done
```

Now `inotifywait -m` works all the time and outputs one line of text per event caught. Then every such a line causes `ls` to be run.

---

Another solution will be `iwatch` and its daemon. Of course setting up a daemon requires root access. Read [my answer to another question](https://superuser.com/a/1131150/432690) and adjust it to your needs.

Additionally you may be interested in [LoggedFS - Filesystem monitoring with FUSE](https://github.com/rflament/loggedfs).

Comment: Thanks buddy, the above works perfectly just one issue it does update the text file when a file is created but it does not recognize when the file is removed through the delete button is keyboard although it does work when `rm` command is used.

Comment: @Nobody The delete button may `mv` the file to trash or so. Try adding a `move` event to the list (i.e. it will be `create,delete,move`). Answer updated.